# Contraction mapping and linear continous operator

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I'm working on contraction mapping theorem with parameter, and this leads me to Appendix D of ***G. Da Prato, Introduction to stochastic analysis and Malliavin calculus***.

In the book, it says
[image]
[image]

[image]

whereas I have literally no idea why $G$ defined above is a contraction. Please help me with it

Comment: I am unclear as to your confusion. You reproduced the argument leading to $|Gz| \le k|z|, \forall z \in E$. Is there something about the argument you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem is that you don't see why the final inequality holds, note that if you set $\mu =0$ in D.3, and take norms you get $$|F_x(\lambda, x)y| = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac 1{|h|} |F(\lambda, x+hy) - F(\lambda, x)|$$
By D.1, this becomes
$$|F_x(\lambda, x)y| \le \lim_{h\to 0} \frac 1{|h|} k|hy| = k|y|$$
This holds for any $\lambda, x, y$, so we can rewrite it as
$$|F_x(\alpha, u)y| \le k|y|$$

Now, letting $\alpha= \lambda + \xi h\mu,\ u = x(\lambda) + \xi\big(x(\lambda + h\mu) - x(\lambda)\big),\ y = z$, we have
$$|Gz| \le \int_0^1\left|F_x\bigg(\lambda + \xi h\mu,\ x(\lambda) + \xi\big(x(\lambda + h\mu) - x(\lambda)\big)\bigg)z\right|\,d\xi\le\int_0^1 k|z|\,d\xi = k|z|$$